# GWT Widget does not allow long-touch-to-copy selections

Tags: javascript, java, iphone, gwt, dom-events

We're developing a mobile application using GWT and are facing the following problem:

iPhone offer a long touch function to do copy&paste for all kinds of stuff. But when we're using the HTML widget or another widget that has explicit ClickHandlers, those events are not forwarded. This even occurs, when there is no clickhandler defined.

How can we monitor long touches (since there is no click/touchup, the onclick method is not being triggered) and how can we prevent the prevention of such events?

There seems to be no method for removing all events on a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found many more problems with GWT on mobile platforms - basically performance issues with long tables or large contents which made us sit down, think about it and finally throw the stuff away.

We've now developed a native client for Android and iOS - which took in turn about the same time for development as an optimized pseudo-single-html-all-in-all-solution.